# Using random in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a random number guessing game but I cant get the if statement to check if the users input is = to the random number

```
import random

realNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
print(realNumber)

myNumber = print(input("Guess the number from 1 to 50: "))

if int(myNumber) == realNumber:
    print("You win")
else:
    print("Nope guess again")
```

Comment: `myNumber` will always be `None` because you have an unnecessary `print()` call. `myNumber = input("Guess the number from 1 to 50: ")` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The unintended behavior of your program is due to this line:

```
myNumber = print(input("Guess the number from 1 to 50: "))
```

Here, you are trying to assign `myNumber` to the return value of the *print* statement (Which is `None`) and not the value obtained from the `input()` statement. To fix this, simply remove the `print()` around the input.

```
myNumber = input("Guess the number from 1 to 50: ")
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the print statement around `input`.

```
import random

realNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
print(realNumber)

myNumber = input("Guess the number from 1 to 50: ")

if int(myNumber) == realNumber:
    print("You win")
else:
    print("Nope guess again")
```

Note that this code will not work if the user enters something besides an integer, because the `int()` call will not cast correctly